# In Dajango How import a function from another view?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have this folder hierarchy:

```
|---- ksy
   |---- shop
      |---- views.py
   |---- over_time
     |---- views.py
```

On my `shop/views.py`, I have this functions:

```
def check_consumed_hour(request, job_no, booked_hour):
    estimate_hour, consumed_hour = 0.0, 0.0
    obj_job = JobNumbers.objects.get(Q(job_no=job_no))
    total_consumed_hour = float(obj_job.consumed_hour)
    for job in obj_job.estimatedhours_set.all():
        if request.user.userinform.section in job.shop_name:
            estimate_hour = float(job.man_hour)
        else:
            pass
    for job in obj_job.consumedhours_set.all():
        if request.user.userinform.section in job.shop_name:
            consumed_hour = float(job.man_hour)
        else:
            pass
    balance_hour = estimate_hour - consumed_hour
    book_hour = float(booked_hour)
    # if balance_hour >= book_hour:  # ESTIMATED HOUR EXCEED MSG SHOW.
    for job in obj_job.consumedhours_set.all():
        if request.user.userinform.section in job.shop_name:
            man_hour = float(job.man_hour)
            man_hour += book_hour
            job.man_hour = str(man_hour)
            job.save()
            total_consumed_hour += book_hour
            obj_job.consumed_hour = str(total_consumed_hour)
            obj_job.save()
            return True
        else:
            pass
```

On my `over_time/views.py`, I need the `check_consumed_hour()` function, so I'm importing like this:

```
from shop.views import check_consumed_hour
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
from shop.views import check_consumed_hour
ImportError: cannot import name 'check_consumed_hour'
```

How can I make this importation? I don't want to reply all code.

Comment: Where is `core`? In your file tree, you only mentioned `over_time`. Also, are these `shop`, `over_time`, etc. individual apps?

Comment: I don't see core

Comment: `from ..shop.views import check_consumed_hour`? note the `..`

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano `core` is my typing mistake. there was `over_time/view.py` .Thanks

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat try with ``..` but error like this `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: Is `ksy` the directory that has the `manage.py` file?

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file in `ksy/`? If so, you'll have to be importing as `from ksy.shop.views import <name>`. If you don't have `__init__.py` defined in `shop/`, make sure you plug that both in there and in `over_time/`.

Comment: Assuming `ksy` is the root of your project, containing the `manage.py` and the apps `shop` and `over_time`, I tried it on my end and your import is working `from shop.views import check_consumed_hour`. Maybe you can check the actual name of the directories, files, and the function name for any typo.

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback. Likely you import something that has not been loaded yet. Also share the `INSTALLLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: Thanks everyone i found solutions, but didn't find reason of error: in my `over_time/views.py` first import views `from shop import views` then i declare fuction `check_hour = views.check_consumed_hour(request, job_no, booked_hour)` it is work for me.